# Handlebars conditional class attributes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using EmberJS/Handlebars, how can I add a class to an element, only if a condition is true?

```
<div {{#if isSearching}}class="foo"{{/if}}></div>
```

Like that, but less pseudocode and more reality.

Comment: Well, that's working. You can send a class list as a template data variable and use it instead if you prefer process these thing outside the template. Or you can use custom helper method... But really, what you got is the simpler way.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias But it doesn't work. It escapes all of the properties after the if statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That won't work, because the `{{#if}}` helper will create tags in your HTML. Do this instead:

```
<div {{bind-attr class="isSearching:foo"}}></div>
```

Comment: bindAttr is the "old" Ember syntax btw (not used with the more recent versions).

Comment: (it's called bind-attr in the new one)

Answer (score 53):

{{bind-attr}} is [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-deprecations-in-1-13). You can use the new much nicer [bound attribute syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax) in Ember 1.10 and above, like so:

```
<div class="{{if isSearching 'foo'}}"></div>
```

Comment: @adam it is for ember 1.11

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the `{{bind-attr}}` helper with a boolean condition, you can [read the guide about this](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/#toc_binding-to-boolean-values).

In your case, if the isSearching property is in the controller, you can just do the following:

```
<div {{bind-attr class="isSearching:foo"}}></div>
```

You can see the whole code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/240/

Comment: Your link to the guide is broken.